# Displaying text from a loop using ttf

Tags: c++, sdl-ttf

I want to display text from a vector using ttf. My code so far:

```
SDL_Surface * Csurface::onLoadText(const char* text, TTF_Font* font, SDL_Color text_color) {
    OutputDebugString("Csurface.cpp onLoadText called\n");
    SDL_Surface *surf_return = NULL;

    surf_return = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, text, text_color);

    if (surf_return == NULL) {
        return false;
    }else {
        return surf_return;
    }
}
```

Here I am trying to render the text from the vector:

```
else if (display_list_incredients) {
    Csurface::OnDraw(surf_display, surf_list_incredients, 0, 0);
    Csurface::OnDraw(surf_list_incredients, surf_budget, SCREEN_WIDTH / 100 * 1, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 100 * 2);
    Csurface::OnDraw(surf_budget, surf_text_budget, 20, 80);

    I_GameLogic i_game_logic;
    int y = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 100 *25;
    int i_max = v_incredients.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < i_max; i++) {
        Csurface::OnDraw(surf_list_incredients, surf_button_buy, SCREEN_WIDTH / 100 * 5, y);
        std::string text_incredient = i_game_logic.get_text_incredient(v_incredients[i]);
        OutputDebugString(text_incredient.c_str());
        surf_text_incredient = Csurface::onLoadText(text_incredient.c_str(), font, text_color);
        Csurface::OnDraw(surf_button_buy, surf_text_incredient, 0,0);
        y+= SCREEN_HEIGHT / 100 * 5;
    }

}
```

In the text surfaces it seems, that all single incredients are rendered over each other.

```
bool Csurface::OnDraw(SDL_Surface* Surf_Dest, SDL_Surface* Surf_Src, int X, int Y) {

    if (Surf_Dest == NULL || Surf_Src == NULL) {
        return false;
    }

    SDL_Rect DestR;

    DestR.x = X;
    DestR.y = Y;

    SDL_BlitSurface(Surf_Src, NULL, Surf_Dest, &DestR);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. There are no any question in your text. What is your question?

Comment: How to render the text from a vector correctly? (meaning a single line for each item from the vecor)

Comment: Ok, show us implementation of your `Csurface::OnDraw()`. It looks that you need to set coordinates somewhere. Aren't third and fourth parameters of this functions `x` and `y` coordinates?

Comment: I have found my mistake, I am drawing the text in each loop in each of the button fields. I am now rendering the text to the background and this works.

Comment: Ok, write it in the answer field and mark as "Correct" (to close this question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my mistake, I am drawing the text in each loop in each of the button fields. I am now rendering the text to the background and this works.

```
    Csurface::OnDraw(surf_list_incredients, surf_button_buy, x_buttons, y);
    std::string text_incredient = i_game_logic.get_text_incredient(v_incredients[i]);
    surf_text_incredient = Csurface::onLoadText(text_incredient.c_str(), font, text_color);
    Csurface::OnDraw(surf_list_incredients, surf_text_incredient, x_text, y);
    y+= SCREEN_HEIGHT / 100 * 7;
```